# How to get notified the latest recv in socket(python)

Tags: python

```
sock.setblocking(0)
ready = select.select([sock], [], [], timeout)
try:
    if ready[0]:
        status = sock.recv(1024)
        return status
    else:
        print "Time out Occured, Disconnecting..."
```

I have socket receive function which receives whenever some status gets changed in client side. Meanwhile, I will process other activities.

since I get the sock receive between some other activities I miss that receive and could not process that receive.

so how could I get latest receive whenever I want!

please note am a newbie in python.

Comment: What type of socket is `sock`? Because the whole concept of *missing a receive* (or rather missing a packet) only makes sense for datagram sockets ...

Comment: It is a socket created with socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM

Comment: What makes you think that you *missed a receive*? `SOCK_STREAM` guarantees you sequential delivery, so you cannot *miss out* on data. The data is still waiting for you in the socket buffer, even with non-blocking IO, unless the connection broke while you are not accessing it, but that will give you a proper error message.

Comment: I will be doing some other process at that time. So i cant parse the recv at the time.

Comment: Short answer: Don't do the `recv()` until you have time to parse it. Longer answer: Spawn a separate thread for the receive and go back to blocking IO.

Comment: @dhke can you please give example for your last comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need background IO, spawning a new thread to handle IO is probably the easiest method:

```
import socket
import threading
import queue

class ClientReceiver(threading.Thread):
    RECV_BUF_SIZE = 1024
    QUEUE_SIZE = 2

    def __init__(self, sock, recv_buf_size=None, queue_size=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClientReceiver, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # set thread as daemon thread, we don't want to
        # wait for this thread on interpreter exit.
        self.setDaemon(True)
        self.sock = sock
        self.recv_buf_size = recv_buf_size or self.RECV_BUF_SIZE
        self.queue_size = queue_size or self.QUEUE_SIZE

    def run(self):
        sock = self.sock
        try:
            while True:
                data = sock.recv(self.recv_buf_size)
                self.queue.put(data)            
        except Exception as ex:      
            # handle errors     
            raise

# Usage example:
sock = ...
receiver = ClientReceiver(sock)                         
receiver.start()
data = receiver.queue.get(block=False)
```

The thread retrieves data from the network as soon as it is available and puts it into a queue. The thread blocks if the queue is full, you may or may not want another strategy.

Retrieve data from the queue at any time using [`receiver.queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).

This is missing code for proper client socket shutdown, but you probably get the basic idea.

Comment: Getting Attribute Error : Queue instance has no attribute __trunc__.

Comment: @taz your are getting this error from which line? Which version of Python are you using?